# Unable to locate the source of a Clojure function

Tags: clojure

I'm not a Clojure programmer, but I've been tasked to rewrite a core piece of our architecture from it's current Clojure into Node. If you love Clojure and you're wondering why, we can't get Clojure developers anywhere, and JavaScript is pretty universal (at least the being able to read it part). The component itself is small and simple enough, but the lack of Clojure expertise is really holding us back at the moment.

I understand the majority of the code, but I've encountered a function named `<fn` which I can't find online (possibly because it's hard to search the special character), in the Clojure docs, or any `defn` within our code.

Here it is in a bit of context

```
(comp (<fn plan/enqueue nil handle-internal-event)
      (<fn doto mt/confirm!)
      sanitize-object)
```

Any clues on what this would be doing? Is it a simple expression I've overlooked, or is it likely some sort of lisp macro thing?

**Answered**

Turns out it was a macro that was required at the top of my file.

```
(:require [fletching.macros :refer :all])
```

For anyone interested in the source code of this function it is at
https://github.com/jdevuyst/fletching-macros

Comment: The `require` or `use` of that file should make it obvious (or in case of `use` make the choices smaller). If that does not help, it's either defined beforehand in the same file or it's from core (which it isn't). In the REPL you can also do `(source <fn)`.

Comment: And i guess it's something like `(fn <fn [f & args] #(apply f % args))`

Comment: Ah. Nailed it, I found `[fletching.macros :refer :all]` in my require, github had the API for it. If you add as an answer I will mark it

Comment: From what I can tell (from the jobs-discuss and remote-jobs slack groups) there is a surplus of Clojure developers willing to work remotely. That's at odds with 'can't get Clojure developers anywhere'.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy I'm not the boss, nor do I have any power over who we do or don't hire in the field of Clojure (and you can probably see why from my question). This is what I'm told is the problem. If you were to be cynical, you could say it's because Clojure developers are more expensive, we don't have a lot of Clojure code, so it actually kind of makes sense that they don't want another full timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to track things down like this, goes like this (assuming, this is a
regular source file and we are talking regular Clojure here).

So if your editor or IDE does not help, but you have that code loaded in a REPL, you can do `(source <fn)`.

If the function/macro in question has a namespace prefixed (e.g. `tools*/<fn`),
there is a `require` for it (e.g. `(:require [my.ns.tools :as tools*])`).

If not:

1. Make sure, the function is not defined in the same file beforehand.
2. Make sure, it is no function from `clojure.core`.  E.g. [in the cheatsheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet)
3. Search for things with `require` and `use`, that look like this `(:require [my.ns.tools :refer :all])`, `(:require [my.ns.tools :refer [<fn])`, `(:use [my.ns.tools])`

If all of this does not help, then there is a chance, that this function got created for you by something else.  Examples for that category are the constructor functions for records (e.g. `->A` and `map->A` for the record `A`).  [This is an example](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/blob/c82f0c51016a67deb15fec51ea2952e369365834/src/me/shenfeng/http/client.clj#L124-L139) where a macro is used to create top level functions.

Honourable mention (but not useful in this case): [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/)

Comment: Thank very much. My case was number 3, there was no reference I could find to the actuall text `<fn` as it was required by a `:refer :all`.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question has already been answered, there is a nice hint. Every time you see a function call without a namespace (say, just `(foo)` but not `(namespace/foo)`), it means the function was injected here in one of three ways:

1. via `:use` in `ns` macro, e.g. `(:use some.package)`;
2. via `:require` in `ns` with explicit `refer`: `(:require [some.package :refer [foo]])`
3. via `:require` referring everything inside a package: `(:require [some.package :refer :all])`

So you should examine the `ns` macro placed in the top of file. But the better approach would be to use either emacs + cider and pressing `M-.` to go to symbol definition or at least some IDE with the same feature.